# Same value is getting printed when using *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I'm trying to get distance of each item while iterating.

[Refer this Image for the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92P1z.png)

In the below code, I'm getting the distance from `(onResponse)="getDistance($event)"`

```
  <div *ngFor="let routes of places[0].routes" class="todo-thumbnail-area">
    <agm-map [zoom]="1">
      <agm-direction [origin]="routes.origin" [destination]="routes.destination" (onResponse)="getDistance($event)">
      </agm-direction>
    </agm-map>
    <div class="todo-price">One Way Trip Cost - {{ this.routeTotalDistance }}</div>
  </div>
```

In Component.ts

```
  getDistance (event) {
    this.routeTotalDistance = event.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
  }
```

So in console, if I print the `routeTotalDistance` I see different values for each iteration but at end I see same value for all the items.

I think after the last iteration `routeTotalDistance` is set to last iterated value.

How I can fix this logic issue ? Please guide.

Comment: I don't know what your end goal is, does this answer your question: `this.routeTotalDistance += event.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text`

Comment: if i do that i get this `151 km151 km462 km462 km347 km347 km332 km332 km506 km506`

Comment: @RachidO I've attached an image for your reference

Comment: That's happening because `this.routeTotalDistance` is global for the whole component, instead, you need to have routeTotalDistance for each route

Comment: but how do I declare  a variable for each routes while iterating ?

Answer (score 1):

> I think after the last iteration routeTotalDistance is set to last iterated value.

You are right: every time you call `getDistance` the `routeTotalDistance` variable is overridden. What you could do is make `routeTotalDistance` an array:

```
<div *ngFor="let routes of places[0].routes; let i = index" class="todo-thumbnail-area">
<agm-map [zoom]="1">
  <agm-direction [origin]="routes.origin" [destination]="routes.destination" (onResponse)="getDistance($event, i)">
  </agm-direction>
</agm-map>
<div class="todo-price">One Way Trip Cost - {{ this.routeTotalDistances[i] }}</div>
```

```
routeTotalDistances: string[] = [];

...

getDistance (event, i) {
    this.routeTotalDistances[i] = event.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;
}
```

Comment: i get this error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

Comment: @HighwayCabs how do you declare your `routeTotalDistances` variable? Don't forget to initialize it as an empty array like `routeTotalDistances: string[] = [];`